# Switching limits counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a row of functions that converges non-uniformly to a function $f$.
$$ f_n: A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
Let $a$ be an accumulation point in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$.
Suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f_n(x)$ exists and is finite for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ 
.

There are three questions listed, and the textbook claims that the answers are negative, but I can't find a counterexamples.

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists
- $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_n(x)$ exists
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f_n(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_n(x)$ holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word nonuniformly should give you a clue that we want things to become very steep.  For the first, let $f(x)$ be a step function with the step at $a$ and the $f_n$ be approximations to it getting steeper and steeper near the transition.  So $$f_n(x)=\begin {cases} -1&x \lt a-\frac 1n \\n(x-(a-\frac 1n))& a-\frac 1n \le x \lt a+\frac 1n \\1 & x \ge a+\frac 1n \end {cases}\\f(x)=\begin {cases} -1& x \lt a\\0& x=a\\1& x \gt a\end {cases}$$  Does this help with the others?

Comment: If I'm correct, $lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) = 0$ and also  $lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_n(x) = 0$, so how is this a counterexample?

Comment: Aha! I found my mistake, I was still in the old mindset that a limit must equal the image if the image exists.

Comment: No, $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) $ does not exist.  The limit from the left is $1$, the limit from the right is $-1$

Comment: Now I only need a counterexample for the second question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f_n(x)$=$x^n$ on $[0,1]$ see that $\lim_{x\to 1}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$ and
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{x\to 1}f_n(x)=1$ thus we see that limits are not interchangeable.

Comment: Is this helpful?

Comment: Do you mean $(0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$?

Comment: No,whyd you think so?

Comment: It looks like your first limit might involve a $0^{\infty}$ or $1^{\infty}$ for $[0,1]$. Is there any harm in changing to $(0,1)$?

Comment: I do not think it will because for the first limit,we tend $n$ to $\infty$ first this gives us $f$ which is $1$ at $x=1$ and $0$ elsewhere on $[0,1]$.Then we do $x$ tends to $1$,this gives us $0$.

Comment: You must do one by one,this is not the case of double limits.

Comment: This one is iterated limit.